# How to generate WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE using Consumerid,privatekey in c#.net for walmart I/O

Tags: authentication, signature

Does anyone have c#.net code that can generate WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE for the Walmart API ?I have java code
("https://walmart.io/docs/affiliate/onboarding-guide")tried to wrap my head around the java example but i am not having any luck because i don't have experience of java to convert code in c#.net.I have Consumerid,private key and also public key.need  WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE but code is not working on c#.net.

Comment: Did you find any answer for this?